# POST XML file in AX2012 using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to call an API which accepts a POST request taking as parameter a single XML file. I've tried calling the resource via Postman (with form-data content type) and seems to work correctly. When trying to implement this in AX I get an error 500 from the server.

Here is the POST request:

```
void executeRequest(XmlDocument _data)
{

    clrRequestObject = System.Net.WebRequest::Create("/URL/WEB/API/");
    webRequest = clrRequestObject;

    //Set Method Type
    webRequest.set_Method("POST");
    webRequest.set_CookieContainer(cookieCon);
    webRequest.set_KeepAlive(true);

    new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert();

    // Set Content type
    webRequest.set_ContentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7db2511d20514");
    byteArray = this.getMultipartFormData(_data,"filename");

    inputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    inputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.get_Length());

    webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    inputStream.Close();
    stream.Close();
    webResponse.Close();

}


private System.Byte[] getMultipartFormData(XmlDocument _data, str name)
{
    #define.DocFieldFormat('--\%1\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\%2\"; filename=\"\%3\";\r\nContent-Type: ' + '\%4\r\n\r\n')
    #define.Dot('.')

    System.IO.MemoryStream memstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    BinData binData = new BinData();
    System.Byte[] bytes;
    str s;
    XMLWriter xmlWriter;
    str path = WinAPI::getTempPath();
    Filename filename = path+name+".xml";
    System.IO.FileStream fileStream;

    xmlWriter = XmlWriter::newFile(filename);
    _data.writeTo(XmlWriter);
    xmlWriter.close();

        // Header
        s = strFmt(
            #DocFieldFormat,
            ---------------------------7db2511d20514,
            name,
            name+#Dot+"xml",
            "text/xml");
        bytes = encoding.GetBytes(s);
        memstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.get_Length());

        /*Alternative attempt to set content 1*/
        //binData.setStrData(_data.outerXml());
        //bytes = encoding.GetBytes(binData.base64Encode());
        //memstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.get_Length());

        /*Alternative attempt to set content 2*/
        //bytes = encoding.GetBytes(_data.outerXml());
        //memstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.get_Length());

        /*Alternative attempt to set content 3*/
        fileStream = System.IO.File::OpenRead(filename);
        fileStream.CopyTo(memstream);

    }

    s = "\r\n--" + #FormDataBoundary + "--\r\n";
    bytes = encoding.GetBytes(s);
    memstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.get_Length());

    bytes = memstream.ToArray();
    memstream.Close();

    return bytes;
}
```

I'm looking into what the exact error is on the API server in order to help me troubleshoot but looking for any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong. Is there an alternative way of doing this via AX?